# JExcel (jxl): Writing large record set to excel Worksheet fails (OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)

Tags: java, jxl

I'm trying to write a result set (100,000 rows, 45 cols) from a web application to excel using JExcel 2.6.9.

The process fails with:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - Java heap space
at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:1179)
```

I've tried the following:

```
        WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
        ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        ws.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("tempExcel.xls"),ws);
```

so Basically in a while loop, the `ResultSet` from database is iterated and then

`s.addCell(new Label(colIndex, rowIndex, value, format));` is done for each row.

I'm not quit sure how to get pass this issue. There is memory constraints in the env where this application is running from so to simply allocate more RAM for JVM is not an option unless there is absolutely no other way. I would appreciate any feedback on this. Thanks

Comment: I too had this same issue. After googling a lot I came across this link : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api It handles large amount of data easily. For my test program I used 100,000 rows and 50 columns. It wrote into a xls file without any errors. The only issue I faced was the size of the generated excel file. It exceeded 100 MB!!! Other than that its perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put X pounds of anything into a Y sized bag if X > Y.

That's 4.5 million values.  If lots of them are Strings, with an average size of 1K bytes each, you'd have ~4.5GB of data.

If you've got the whole thing in memory at once you're in trouble.  The solution is to chunk it into smaller pieces, commit them, and then create the next chunk.

I'd wonder if any web client needed that much data at once.  Another solution would be better filtering to limit the size of the `ResultSet`.

Comment: I agree with you. I am struggling to get it right with the `chunk it into smaller pieces, commit and create next chunk`. For example if certain amount of data is read in chunks and is committed, JExcel will still need to read the worksheet into memory to add the remaining rows and will fail again with memory error. I can't limit ResultSet as this is used for reporting purposes (business requirements) . Is there any example on how this could be done with JExcel (reading in chunks,commit,continue)...?

Comment: @duffymo Yes, that's great general purpose answer, but haven't you seen that techventure mentioned he used disk to buffer file contents, which I'm sure has enough free space.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at this web page, especially at chapter 8:

http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html#AEN566

Remember that bulk operation are always better!